# Pass post ID to JavaScript outside the loop

Tags: wp-query, wp-enqueue-script, wp-localize-script

I try to pass the post/pages ID to my JavaScript file. url and template_url works but the id just return 0 on every post.

PHP:

```
// Register scripts
wp_enqueue_script('scripts', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/scripts.js', array(), '1.0', true);

// Pass PHP data
wp_localize_script('scripts', 'phpdata', array(
    'template_url' => get_bloginfo('template_url'),
    'url' => get_bloginfo('url'),
    'id' => get_queried_object_id()
));
```

JavaScript:

```
console.log('ID' + phpdata.id);
```

Comment: Are you doing this in the [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_enqueue_scripts/) hook or somewhere else?

Comment: Add your JS to the question please.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee No, just one time in functions.php

Comment: @jdm2112 I've edited the question now

Comment: I think what Howdy is getting at is the order of execution for your code.  Test this before your localize statement.  Does `get_queried_object_id()` return the ID in the PHP or is it 0 there?